# Split file by keyword

Tags: c#, streamreader, edi

In my job we use EDI UNIFACT,and I´m tring to import these messages.
I´m using an open source library that accepts a file (streamreader) and maps the info, the problem is that some of the files I receive don´t have the correct format for this library.

Each message starts at UNB ..., and end on UNZ ...

```
UNB+UNOA:2+
UNH+1+CODECO
.........
UNT+19+1'
UNZ+1+144427'
------------------> I need to separate here 
UNB+UNOA:2+
UNH+1+CODECO
.......
UNT+19+1'
UNZ+1+144427'
.....
```

I already use a streamreader to search for an word, and then reset it.

```
foreach (string filename in Directory.GetFiles(path))
{
  using (var stream = new StreamReader(filename))
  {
    while (!stream.EndOfStream)
    {
      var line = stream.ReadLine();
      if (line.Contains(@"CODECO")) //Codeco
      {
        stream.DiscardBufferedData();
        stream.BaseStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var grammar_read = EdiGrammar.NewEdiFact();
        var interchange = default(Interchange<CODECO_D95B>);
        interchange = new EdiSerializer().Deserialize<Interchange<CODECO_D95B>>(stream, grammar_read);
        if (interchange != null)
          list.AddRange(ImportCODECO(interchange));               
       }
    }
 }
```

My question is, split these files, so I can input each chunk off information separately as it came from a file?

Many thanks

Comment: This is a specialized format, and you would usually use a specialized parser to parse it. There are a few floating about

Comment: I got a parser that works if it is only between UNB and UNZ, that´s why I need to split each file into multiple files. Or ideally re-use the streamreader and feed it chunk by chunk...

Comment: Use `FIle.ReadLines` and then group the lines into chunks either with an extension method (mine is `GroupByWhile`) or using a counter and regular `GroupBy`.

Answer (score 0):

To separate and gather the content between you need to create a starting state and ending state, that get reset each start end cycle is done. In each cycle you gather the data in StringBuilder and to a for example a list.

I have made a conceptual working solution that I am pretty sure can be optimized later on.

For this I created input like:

```
UNB+UNOA:2+
UNH+1+CODECO
My text1 chunk1
My text2 chunk1
My text3 chunk1
UNT+19+1'
UNZ+1+144427'
UNB+UNOA:2+
UNH+1+CODECO
My text1 chunk2
My text2 chunk2
My text3 chunk2
UNT+19+1'
UNZ+1+144427'
```

so I will separate first and second one and gather the chunk data between.

```
string startSyntax1 = "UNB+UNOA:2+";
string startSyntax2 = "UNH+1+CODECO";
string endSyntax1 = "UNT+19+1'";
string endSyntax2 = "UNZ+1+144427'";
List<string> chunks = new List<string>();
bool startState = false;
bool endState = false;
StringBuilder sb = null;

foreach (var s in lines)
{
    if (s.StartsWith(startSyntax1) && !startState)
    {
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        startState = true;
    }

    if (startState)
    {
        if (!startSyntax1.StartsWith(s) && !startSyntax2.StartsWith(s) && !endSyntax1.StartsWith(s) && !endSyntax2.StartsWith(s))
        {
            sb.Append($"{s}{Environment.NewLine}");
        }
        endState = s.StartsWith(endSyntax2);
    }

    if (startState && endState)
    {
        var text = sb.ToString();
        chunks.Add(text);
        startState = false;
        endState = false;
    }
}
```

If we now print the list we get following output:

```
My text1 chunk1
My text2 chunk1
My text3 chunk1

My text1 chunk2
My text2 chunk2
My text3 chunk2
```